Android Room: Retrieving data from the database that will not change
I keep data that will not change in the android room database. These data are the questions in the question table and the answers to these questions in the answer table.
What is the best way to pull this data?
When I use Flow and StateFlow, it becomes unnecessary because this data will never change. Normally I would keep this data in a static file or variable, but there will be too many questions and answers and not all of the data will be needed at the same time.
What practice would you recommend in this scenario?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
